# Delete or Overwrite a SharePoint List using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am able to add easily create a SharePoint List using Excel VBA with the following code snippet:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Publish Array( _
    "http://sitebuilder2.xyzcompany.com/operations", "test1"), False
```

However, I get an "Run-time error '3003': Application-defined or object-defined error" if I use the same list name ("test1") because the list already exists.

Is there a straight-forward way to either overwrite list ("test1"), or delete list ("test1") in SharePoint using Excel VBA, so that I can update the entire list without providing a new List name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to synchronize to the SharePoint list using this code.

```
Private Sub PublishRW()
  Dim listPoint As Range
  Dim fullServerName As String
  Dim retUrl As String
  
  Set listPoint = ActiveCell.ListObject.Range(1, 1)
  fullServerName = ServerName.Value & "_vti_bin"
  
  If ListDescription.Value = "" Then
    retUrl = ActiveCell.ListObject.Publish(Array(ServerName.Value, ListName.Value), False)
  Else
    retUrl = ActiveCell.ListObject.Publish(Array(ServerName.Value, ListName.Value, ListDescription.Value), False)
  End If
  
  If retUrl <> "" Then
    ActiveCell.ListObject.Delete
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add xlSrcExternal, Array(fullServerName, ListName.Value), True, xlYes, listPoint
  Else
    MsgBox "There was an error during publish, please check the server name"
  End If
  Unload ExportRWList
End Sub
```

Comment: I would really like to try this, can you please let me know where I should be changing my site name and list details?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  I started by creating a SharePoint list with the needed fields, and Exported that template to Excel ("Export to Excel").  Then I developed the above VBA code to publish updates back to the SharePoint list.